# If loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to create 3 folders (named as In,Proc,Error) in C:\Ram directory. First I need to check for folder existence in directory. If any of them not present need to create missing folder. If all missed need to create all 3. Could anyone suggest a simple looping code in VB.NET for this requirement .

Comment: We aren't going to do the work for you.  At the very least, you should try yourself first, and if unsuccessful, post that code and then we can help you.

Comment: Do we also need to check if C:\ram exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim folders = New () { "In", "Proc", "Error" }
For Each folder As String In folders
    Dim dir = Path.Combine("c:\ram", folder)
    If Not Directory.Exists(dir) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Just a thought, is it necessary to check the directory exists, I think the code would work the same without the check.

Comment: You don't need to check it. VS will create all folder level for you.